# Low poly to higher poly. Keep UVs

Tags: subdivision-surface, polycount

I am very new to 3d modeling. I have an existing low poly mesh and some textures that work great for it.

I want to make it more smooth and it sounds like I want https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html

However, I've read this can distort my UVs and I already have a texture I want to keep.

How can I keep the UVs nearly identical and increase the smoothness.

I am looking for native blender methodology or plugins

Comment: Why not just try it, present the results and ask if they can be improved (by describing your expectations)? You can duplicate an object, apply subidivision surface, select both objects and enter the UV editing to see how close is one UV mapping to the other. https://i.imgur.com/qS9FMvQ.jpeg

Comment: Will do when I'm home. I was waiting for my car to finish and I was researching how to do it before I got home. Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 5):

The [Subdivision Surface](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html) modifier has a *UV Smooth* setting

[image]

Comparison on Susanne:

[image]